# Python CherryPy server, what does cherrypy.Application do?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have here a Python program.
It uses CherryPy to create a server.

```
# coding:utf-8

import os.path
import cherrypy

from app import application

def main():

try:                                   
    currentDir_s = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except:
    currentDir_s = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable))
cherrypy.Application.currentDir_s = currentDir_s

configFileName_s = 'server.conf'
if os.path.exists(configFileName_s) == False:
    configFileName_s = None

cherrypy.engine.autoreload.unsubscribe()
cherrypy.engine.timeout_monitor.unsubscribe()

cherrypy.quickstart(application.Application_cl(), config=configFileName_s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And in "server.conf" it configure the server:

```
[global]
tools.log_headers.on: True
tools.sessions.on:    False  
tools.encode.on:      True
tools.encode.encoding:"utf-8"

server.socket_port:   8080 
server.socket_timeout:60     

server.thread_pool:  10      
server.environment:  "production"
log.screen:          True    

[/]
tools.staticdir.root: cherrypy.Application.currentDir_s
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = '.'
```

There is one thing, I don't understand, this line (line 13 in the python code):

```
cherrypy.Application.currentDir_s = currentDir_s
```

I searched in the internet about this, but I couldn't find anything. What does "cherrypy.Application" do? Why I have to do this assignment (cherrypy.Application.currentDir_s = currentDir_s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the cherrypy source code and here is what I found.
In `_cptree.py` module you will find the `Application` class. Below that, there is a `Tree` class which has `mount` method which we are used to binding applications with (e.g. `cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), "/", config=config)`)

```
def mount(self, root, script_name="", config=None):
    ...
```

When you look inside this method you will see the code below;

```
def mount(self, root, script_name="", config=None):
    ...
    if isinstance(root, Application):
        app = root
        if script_name != "" and script_name != app.script_name:
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot specify a different script name and pass an "
                "Application instance to cherrypy.mount")
        script_name = app.script_name
    else:
        app = Application(root, script_name)

        # If mounted at "", add favicon.ico
        if (script_name == "" and root is not None
                and not hasattr(root, "favicon_ico")):
            favicon = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   "favicon.ico")
            root.favicon_ico = tools.staticfile.handler(favicon)

    if config:
        app.merge(config)

    self.apps[script_name] = app
```

So, the code says that every object (application) you pass to the `mount` method is either `Application` instance or wrapped in an `Application` instance. So why is that so? When you check `Application` class above `Tree` class, you will see a `__call__` method like below;

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    return self.wsgiapp(environ, start_response)
```

Yes you see it now, it is [`wsgi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) interface.
Therefore, `Application` is a wsgi wrapper for your cherrypy applications.
When you check the source code of cherrypy you may learn lots of things. I hope this answer help you.